# Sitecore form submit action working on form and not working when using in a view as rendering call

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am facing a weird issue, I have created a Sitecore form in Sitecore 10 version, in which I have created a custom email submit action which is also working perfectly fine.

The issue is, when I am using that form rendering on a view, that submit action is redirecting to *IIS 404.15* which says that

[image]

I have given that form in that view as

```
@if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
 {
   @Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{6B5TREE6-5C85-4487-BA7E-F8C2ECC186A8}", new { DataSource = "{4CC39BCB-9060-4B5B-ADD6-315CGD76652B}" })
 }
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: How did you confirm that the submit action is working when you can't use it on a page? The error suggest an issue with a query string - which call is being made at that moment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sitecore form, then above {4CC39BCB-9060-4B5B-ADD6-315CGD76652B} must be used as datasource on MVC Form rendering.

Can you confirm about rendering id {6B5TREE6-5C85-4487-BA7E-F8C2ECC186A8}" is for MVC Form?

For reference look at https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html

Comment: Yes, everything is correct, otherwise the form would not have shown up on the item itself., the issue is, submit action is not working when I am rendering a form on an item, if I browse the form itself, it is working perfectly fine.